# error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and I would like to know how to use the sort function.
This is my code and it's not working for some reasons:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in("date.in");
    ofstream out("date.out");
    int v[5]= {2, 3 ,1, 0, 5};
    sort(begin(v), end(v));
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        out<<v[j]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error code I get is:

> error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope

Comment: I recommend e.g. [this `std::begin` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). You're simply not including the correct header file.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/AMbN3R) - maybe you're not compiling this as C++14 (or later) ?

Comment: I think including the iterator header should solve this. If you get an error like this, you should check the documentation to find out where that function is defined.

Comment: `v` is not a vector, but an array. AFAIK there is no function named `begin` in `<algorithm>` that takes arguments of type `int *`. You wish to use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @TInyT: works find as it is if you compile as C++14 or later: http://ideone.com/AMbN3R

Comment: @PaulR thanks for clearing that up. Which `begin/end` does it specialize?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: @TinyT: I think it's the one marked (2) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) - works in C++11 too, I suspect, but I've only tried it with C++14.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, so the solution would be to either replace `<vector>` with `<iterator>` or use `vector<int>` and its `begin/end` members. Still a bit confused as to why [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) would accept pointers as input (which the function you linked would return), but if it builds for you there must be some kind of conversion.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the `#include <iterator>`. Because `std::begin` defined under [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator).

Or else change the type from `array` to `vector` and your code will work.

Comment: The OP's code didn't depend on allocators. Your suggestion would make it so :-(

Comment: The type was array, not `array`.  `array` provides `begin()` and `end()`, unlike arrays, which only get them if you include `<iterator>`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions.

std::sort takes an iterator to the start of the sequence, and one to one past the end of the sequence. This is the convention for stl algorithms which work on collections.

So

```
 std::vector v = {2, 3, 0, 1, 5};
 sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

or

```
 int v[5] = {2, 3, 0, 1, 5};
 sort(v, v + 5);
```

plain pointers are iterators as well as stl::iterator types declared in the stl headers.

Answer (score 0):

replace `sort(begin(v), end(v));` with `sort(v, v + 5));`
`v` is an **array** not a **vector**. For vectors use `sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to your code:

```
#include<algorithm>
```